# how to store output in variable when a command is executed from Jenkins on remote machine via ssh?

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins

I am trying to to do ssh to a VM and getting list of files of a folder, storing result it in a variable in Jenkins execute shell

```
*sshpass -p password ssh -T -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" user@SERVER << ENDHERE

cd /some/folder/

folder=$(ls -l) 

echo $folder

ENDHERE*
```

`echo $folder` is blank but if i do `ls -l` directly on execute shell, it shows list in Jenkins console not not getting stored in `$folder`.

Please help.

Comment: are you trying copy all files from a folder to another folder or just get the list of files and print it ?

Comment: Just trying to get list of files and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your here document is like a double-quoted string; the `$(ls -l)` and `$folder` are evaluated *before* the contents are used as a script on the remote host. Quote the delimiter to have it treated like a single-quoted string.

```
... << 'ENDHERE'
cd /some/folder
folder=$(ls -l)
echo "$folder"
ENDHERE
```